# Find a number of obtainable shares given an average price in LMSR

Tags: calculus, probability

### **What is LMSR**

Logarithmic Market Scoring Rule is an automated market maker formula for prediction markets.

Imagine a market with two outcomes A and B where participants may purchase so called Arrow-Debreu securities or simply put: shares for each of these two outcomes. Each share pays \$1 if corresponding event happens and \$0 otherwise, and current share price is current probability of corresponding event.

LMSR is a cost formula which can be used to find out how much money a user should spend to obtain a desirable amount of shares for a given outcome. For a two-outcome event it looks like this:

$$Cost(q_1, q_2, b) = b \cdot \log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b})$$

Where $q_1, q_2$ are current numbers of purchased shares for outcomes A and B and $b$ is an arbitrary "liquidity parameter". This cost function captures current market state and if user actually wants to find out an amount of money they need to purchase, say, 5 shares for outcome A, then the following should be applied:

$$CostFor5SharesOfQ_1(q_1, q_2, b) = Cost(q_1 + 5, q_2, b) - Cost(q_1, q_2, b)$$

As far as I understand above is a definite integral from $q_1$ to $q_1 + 5$ of a "current price" function. This $Price$ function can be derived from $Cost$ function, for example, a partial derivative with respect to $q_1$ would tell us a "current price for infinitesimal number of $q_1$ shares" and it is also a "current probability" of outcome A:

$$PriceQ_1 = \frac d{d(q_1)}Cost = e^{q_1/b} / (e^{q_1/b} + e^{q_2/b})$$

### **My problem**

I want to find a formula which would answer the following: **"how many shares can be obtained for a given outcome such that average price per share is X"** where $X$ is provided by me.

An example: once again, suppose there is an event with A and B outcomes, no shares are obtained yet so $q_1 = q_2 = 0$ and "liquidity parameter" $b = 100$. Current infinitesimal price of both outcomes is $0.5$ and if user obtains 100 shares of outcome A, then $Cost(q_1 + 100, q_2, b) - Cost(q_1, q_2, b) = \$62.01$, average price per share would be $\$62.01 / 100 = \$0.62$, and updated infinitesimal price for outcome A would become $\$0.731$.

What I want is a sort of reverse function which when given $\$0.62$ would return 100 (shares), it should somehow take into account that price per share changes non-linearly with each infinitesimal purchase and still arrive at correct answer:

$$SharesFromAverage Q_1 Price(0.62, q_1 = 0, q_2 = 0, b = 100) = 100$$

### **Progress so far**

My intuition for example above is since infinitesimal price before obtaining 100 shares of A is $\$0.5$ and after obtaining them it gets to $\$0.731$, part of these shares will be obtained below $\$0.62$ and the rest of them above that price. This means that at first I have some "savings" until I get to $\$0.62$ and then these savings are getting expended with each purchase above $\$0.62$. This means that $\$0.731$ price level is when my savings become $0$.

So I can define a $Savings$ formula as follows:

$$SavingsQ_1 = 0.62 - PriceQ_1 = 0.62 - e^{q_1/b} / (e^{q_1/b} + e^{q_2/b})$$

Integrating this would yield the following:

$$SavingsIntegral(q_1, q_2, b) = 0.62 \cdot (q_1 + q_2) - b \cdot log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b})$$

And it is my understanding that definite integral from $q_1$ to $q_1 + 100$ would be $0$ for example above, so basically I have to solve the following equation where X is a number of shares which I'm looking for and all the rest is known, my derivations so far:

$$SavingsIntegral(q_1 + X, q_2, b) - SavingsIntegral(q_1, q_2, b) = 0\tag{1}$$

$$0.62 \cdot ((q_1 + X) + q_2) - b \cdot log(e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) - (0.62 \cdot (q_1 + q_2) - b \cdot log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b})) = 0\tag{2}$$

$$0.62 \cdot ((q_1 + X) + q_2) - b \cdot log(e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) - 0.62 \cdot (q_1 + q_2) + b \cdot log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b}) = 0\tag{3}$$

$$0.62X - b \cdot log(e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) + b \cdot log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b}) = 0\tag{4}$$

$$0.62X = b \cdot log(e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) - b \cdot log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b})\tag{5}$$

$$0.62X / b = log(e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) - log(e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b})\tag{6}$$

$$0.62X / b = log((e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) / (e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b}))\tag{7}$$

And this is where I have problems isolating $X$, and also I'm not sure if my intuition is correct, so would greatly appreciate a help here.

Comment: So, you want to solve $(7)$ for $X$ given values of $q_1,q_2,\text{ and }b,$ is that correct?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, $q_1$, $q_2$ and $b$ are known. $0.62$ could be another known variable but I use it as is here given a concrete example above.

Comment: There is no need to invent the Savings function.  You could have started directly from $(5)$: the LHS is the cost of $X$ shares given the desired $0.62$ per share, and the RHS is the cost of $X$ shares based on the $Cost(q_1 + X, q_2, b) - Cost(q_1, q_2, b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at equation $(7):$

$$0.62X / b = \log((e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}) / (e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b}))\tag{7}$$  Take exponentials of both sides:$$
e^{0.62X/b}={e^{(q_1 + X)/b}+e^{q_2/b}\over e^{q_1/b}+e^{q_2/b}}\tag{8}$$  To simplify this a bit, write $$\begin{align}
y &= e^{X/b}\\
k_1 &= e^{q_1/b}\\
k_2 &= e^{q_2/b}
\end{align}$$  Now $(8)$ becomes
$$y^{0.62}={k_1y+k_2\over k_1+k_2}\tag{9}$$
As a final simplification, we write $$a={k_1\over k_1+k_2}$$ and $(9)$ becomes $$y^{0.62}-ay-(1-a)=0\tag{10}$$

With the values $q_1=q_2=0$ given in your problem statement, we have $k_1=k_2=1,$ so $a=.5$, and we want to solve $$y^{0.62}-.5y-.5=0$$

Besides the obvious solution $y=1$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%5E.62-.5y-.5%3D0) gives the solution $y=2.71548$ and by definition, $X=b\log{y}.$  With $b=100$ as stated in the problem, this gives $X=99.8969$

Is this a reasonable answer?  I can't say I understand the problem, so I'm not sure.

Comment: It does seem like reasonable answer, the true answer is exactly $100$ (that is, obtaining $100$ shares of outcome A would make $q_1 = 100$, $q_2 = 0$ and average price for each share would be $\$0.62$). I wonder where does the slight error come from?

Comment: I don't understand the underlying problem, so I can't say.  You ought to try to simplify your post, by using the substitutions I suggested, and formatting the equations a bit better.  I, or someone else, might be able to say more if the math was easier to read.

Comment: I think the slight error is easily accounted by (a) $62$ vs $62.01$ and (b) $y$ is only approximately $2.71548$.  (With the toy example of $100$ shares and $b=100$, the exact solution is $y=e$.)

Comment: Could well be so.

Comment: @antkam how did you get to exact solution? Is there a way to isolate $y = ...$ here?

Comment: @Anton - sorry, no I dont know any way to isolate $y$ from saulspatz's final equation, and I think saulspatz's idea of numerically solving it is the only way in general.  However, I do know that in the toy example the exact solution is $X=100$, so $y = exp(X/b) = exp(100/100) = e$.  The numerical solution $y \approx 2.71548$  is too small by $0.0028$ or about a fraction of $1/1000.$  And the numerical $X\approx 99.89$ is too small by $0.11$ which is also about a fraction of $1/1000.$

Comment: @Anton [cont'd] So the error IMHO can be attributed to (a) $0.62$ not being exact, and (b) small wolfram alpha error.  Indeed, trying $0.6201$ [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%5E.6201-.5y-.5%3D0;+x+%3D+100*log(y)) $y\approx 2.71793$ and $X\approx 99.9869$, both with a fraction error $< 1/7600$.